# Android app icon not showing in some devices

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]Added all icon packs still for some devices default icon is showing.

Comment: just remove `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` from androidManifiest.xml file and try rebuild and run app

Comment: Still not showing

Comment: Which device it's not showing I mean the API level?

Comment: API level 28, Android P

Comment: Add a app icon files in your drawable folder and change it in manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try delete `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `ic_launcher_foreground`!

implement/Create a `folder` in `mipmap` called `ic_launcher_foreground` and attach your laucher icons and rebuild.
dont forget `hdpi` , `mdpi` ,  `xhdpi` , `xxhdpi` , `xxxhdpi`

For API 26 and above you need this.